# How to pivot output in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Input:

### Table1->Student  details

```
sno    sname     scourse    sjoindate
1    Ram         bsc        11/26/2011
2    Sham        bcom       10/06/2010
3    Krishna     ba         06/16/2012
```

### Table2->Student marks

```
sno     id      marks
1       1       67  
1       2       77
1       3       80
1       4       60
1       5       90
```

### Table3->Subjectnames

```
id      subjectname
1       Computerscience
2       Maths
3       Satatistics
4       English
5       Hindi
```

### Table4->Student_feedback_QuestionandAnswer

```
sno     Questions       Answers
1        Q1             A1
1        Q2             A2  
1        Q3             A3
1        Q4             A4
```

### Expected Output:

```
sno     sname       scourse     sjoindate       Computerscience      Maths      Statistics      English     Hindi       Questions       Answers
1       Ram         bsc         11/26/2011          67                  77      80               60         90          Q1              A1
                                    Q2              A2
                                    Q3              A3
                                    Q4              A4
```

In the above tables the rows of Table2 and Table3 can increase and decrease depending on the studentname.

I need  tabled to combine the data from all four tables into one result set but I don't know how to use pivot with dynamic header with dynamic column values:

- Data from `Table3.Subjectname` column values should be header column names e.g. Computerscience, Hindi.
- Data from `Table2.marks` should be the value under the header column name e.g. `marks` for `id=`1 under Computerscience.
- the Questions, Answers column from Table4  should come in result set depending on the value of `Table1.sno'

If you can provide a hint for creating a table using pivot with dynamic header with dynamic column values ,yeah using two tables.

Please let me know for more clarification.

Comment: have you tried anything at all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a "please do all my work for me" request.

Comment: @DanBracuk -  something about friday's uh

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Copied title "How to Pivot output in SQL Server 2012" to google - first result : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx